# Redirect to the referrer using ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a login and I want to redirect the user to the referred url after the login. I noticed that MVC automatically sets teh `ReturnUrl` query string, but how to bring that in the POST method of the controller? I tried with `Request["ReturnUrl"]` or `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` but all of them are set to `null`

Answer (score 0):

As far as you see ReturnUrl in your query string, you can get it using a simple code like this:

```
private string GetReturnUrl()
{
    var baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority;
    var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        return baseUrl;
    return baseUrl + returnUrl;
}
```